# Cursor of EditText in ExpandableListView does not blink or appear

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, cursor, expandablelistview

I have an EditText in every child item of the ExpandableListView,
but there is an issue:
when I click the EditText,sometimes the cursor is blinking normally,
but sometimes the cursor will not appear,
or the cursor appear but not blink.

I have tried many ways,but no one is working.

The below is the ways I have tried but not working:

1. set for every EditText of child in Java

   ```
   View.OnFocusChangeListener onFocus = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
           v.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
       }
   };
   ```
2. set for ExpandableListView

   ```
   android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
   android:focusable="false"
   ```
3. set for the child item in xml

   ```
       android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
       android:cursorVisible="true"
   ```

I have no idea about this issue,please help,very thanks ~~~

Comment: have u added android:focusableInTouchMode="true" and android:focusable="false" in child item?

Comment: @Nas Thanks~ I just tried your code,it does not work. TAT

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

As I found out it happening when `EditText`'s inner invalidate timer on some reason stops. I don't have any idea why.

All I could make is to create my own `Handler` to invalidate view inside my class extending `EditText`.

```
@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    if(focused) {
        handler.postDelayed(this, 200);
    } else {
        handler.removeCallbacks(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    invalidate();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(250);
                if(hasFocus()) {
                    handler.post(MyEditText.this);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I don't think it is a good solution. If you know better please write it.